# Javascript string not getting concatenated variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a HTML form I'm creating dynamic HTML elements using jquery/ javascript. To give different IDs to dynamic elements I'm using a loop iteration variable. My idea was with loop it will automatically give iteration number as ID but in HTML I saw it is using first iteration digit value for all elements.

For example if I pass 2 it generate 2 controls with same IDs. Why is that? To me this behavior of JS is weird. Can you please guide what is causing this? Loop works for the number of times passed to function but it is not displaying correct number as a part of IDs.

```
  function CreateDependentForms(noOfControlsToCreats)
    {
        var itrator = 1;
        var sectionFName ="<div id=Dependent"+ itrator +"FName " +"class=\"field rf-field\"><label>First Name</label><input type=\"text\" required=\"\" placeholder=\"eg. Joe\" name=\"partNerfirstname\" aria-required=\"true\"></div>";

        for (;itrator<noOfDependents; itrator++)
        {               
            alert(sectionFName);
            $('#dependentfrequency').after(sectionFName);
        }
}
```

Comment: Because you generate `sectionName` only once outside of the loop?

Comment: @skobaljic I understand that but what is this behaviour ? In other languages it will get value of variable on the time of usage. Is it a particular feature of JS ?

Comment: I learned and know basics of many languages, but have never heard about such. What language you are talking about? Prolog?

Comment: @skobaljic I m guessing any server side language, C# for instance

Comment: No, in JS you have a scopes of variables and values are processed on first pass. In case var is not defined by time you requested, than you get error `undefined`. [More about scopes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and [even more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: @user576510: I don't think I've heard of any language that does this.  C# acts the same way JavaScript does in regards to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CreateDependentForms(noOfControlsToCreats)
{
    var itrator = 1;
    var sectionFName ;




    for (;itrator<noOfDependents; itrator++)
    {               
 sectionName = ="<div id=Dependent"+ itrator +"FName " +"class=\"field rf-field\">   <label>First Name</label><input type=\"text\" required=\"\" placeholder=\"eg. Joe\" name=\"partNerfirstname\" aria-required=\"true\"></div>";       
alert(sectionFName);
        $('#dependentfrequency').after(sectionFName);
    }
```

}

This piece of code will work for you. 
Since in the code you mentioned sectionName was getting initialized ony once and it was given the id of 1 only once which was not changing. Hence, you ended up only one id.

Now once this line is executed, you are ultimately using the same variable over and over again. I have worked in PHP, Java and JS and I have not seen any exception to this. So for me yes, this is how it works and that was the only reason.

Hope this helps something.
Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 2):

The part where you create your HTML contents is outside of your loop. Moving the declaration of `var sectionFName` inside your loop will yield unique IDs for your elements.

```
function CreateDependentForms(noOfControlsToCreats) {
    for (var itrator = 1; itrator < noOfDependents; itrator++) {               
        var sectionFName ="<div id=Dependent"+ itrator +"FName " +"class=\"field rf-field\"><label>First Name</label><input type=\"text\" required=\"\" placeholder=\"eg. Joe\" name=\"partNerfirstname\" aria-required=\"true\"></div>";

        $('#dependentfrequency').after(sectionFName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that and I believe it will fix as well but what is this behavior called ? In other languages it will get value of variable on the time of usage. Is it a particular feature of JS ?

Comment: The time of usage in this case is when you create the string, so it actually does get the value of the variable at the time of usage. I can't think of any language in which a similar pattern would yield a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is built when you declare it.  In your `for` loop, your `sectionFName` string is `"<div id=Dependent1 ..."`.  This is because you've declared it as that.  Incrementing `itrator` in your loop isn't doing to change your string.

```
for (var itrator = 1;itrator<noOfDependents; itrator++)
{
    var sectionFName ="<div id=Dependent"+ itrator +"FName " +"class=\"field rf-field\"><label>First Name</label><input type=\"text\" required=\"\" placeholder=\"eg. Joe\" name=\"partNerfirstname\" aria-required=\"true\"></div>";
    alert(sectionFName);
    $('#dependentfrequency').after(sectionFName);
}
```

Comment: I understand that and I believe it will fix as well but what is this behavior called ? In other languages it will get value of variable on the time of usage. Is it a particular feature of JS ?

Comment: @user576510: I'm not sure what "behavior" you are referring to.  In JavaScript, PHP and other languages I've used, when you concatenate a variable to a string, the operation happens then and there.  The string is *immediately* updated.  I've never heard of or seen the behavior you are thinking of.